# Modifying the markup in the Tag Cloud widget?

Tags: themes, widgets, html

I need to modify the markup of the tag cloud widget.

Can someone tell me how to go about doing this without modifying any of the files outside of the theme directory so my changes don't get overwritten when updating WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sort of custom markup do you need? Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Rather than just have a bunch of anchors, I need to insert them into <li> tags and float the list items so there can several columns.I know I could apply this to the anchors, but I want those to be set to display: inline (since they're text links).

Comment: <?php the_tags('<ul><li>','</li><li>','</li></ul>'); ?>

Comment: Then just float the li tags with CSS

Comment: @Pippin, thanks for the response. This appears to be code to insert for each post. I need to display a tag cloud in the sidebar that contains tags used in all posts. When I tried inserting your code, it didn't print any thing out. What needs to be changed in order for the_tags() to work in the sidebar?

Comment: @Pippin, Nevermind, I figured out that wp_tag_cloud() needs to be used instead. Thanks!

Comment: Your question would have been better posted as a comment to the question, since you're not actually providing an answer in your answer, just a suggestion for next time.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to change the way the tag cloud is displayed, you can use [get_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags) to heavily alter the output and create a custom widget.